# ios app shows only background color when packged using Adobe Developer Tool (ADT command)

Tags: ios, apache-flex

I am having a Flex web project and its compiled build (sample.swf) , by using this swf file i want to package an ios app using Adobe Developer Tool Command line by the following command.

```
adt -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -keystore ..\cer\Cert.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -provisioning-profile ..\cer\DEMO.mobileprovision ..\bin\sample.ipa sample-app.xml sample.swf
```

this command creates an ipa package , but when i install that ios app to the my ipad then the application shows only background color no content.

Here is the code of my descripter file:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.9">
    <id>com.mytech.demo</id>
    <filename>sample</filename>
    <name>sample</name>
    <versionNumber>1.1.0</versionNumber>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>sample.swf</content>
        <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
        <transparent>true</transparent>
        <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>
    </initialWindow>
    <!-- iOS specific capabilities -->
    <iPhone> 
        <InfoAdditions> 
            <![CDATA[ 
                <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
                <array>
                    <string>1</string>
                    <string>2</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
                <string>No</string> 
            ]]> 
        </InfoAdditions> 
    </iPhone>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably throwing an RTE and as a result you don't see anything on the screen.  Have you tried connecting it to the debugger and walking through the code?

Comment: Thanks but my code contains only few lines as below:
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
 <s:Panel width="100%" title="Hello World"/>
</s:Application>